TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined, js engine: hermes
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined, js engine: hermes  LOG  Running "Home_service" with {"rootTag":11}  ERROR  Invariant Violation: "Home_service" has not been registered. This can happen if: * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is run
i am geting same error from last 2 days
enter image description here
i want to solve this problem how pls help
enter image description here

Could you update your question so no images are being used? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors
